# Oracle Apex - Classic Report - Set Column Value to the result of a separate SQL query, passing the column value to the query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am using Oracle Apex version 5.0. I have a column in a classic report that is a date value. Upon rendering the report I want to pass this date value to another SQL Query (separate from the main report query), this will then go and retrieve a different text value for the date, which I then want to display back in the original column. So to the user when the screen renders they don't see the original value at all, just the result of the secondary query to which the original value was passed.

It seems like this should be simple but I can't find any like for like example online. I was hoping to just add a query onto the column itself but there seems to be no option under the column options in the builder. It is not possible to return the data in the main SQL query as the original query, and all of the data is from queries and not tables.

I am wondering if Apex has a built in capability (or workaround) to add a query into a cell on a classic report, passing the cells value and then returning the result back into the cell without modifying the classic reports main SQL Query

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] that shows what **you** have attempted and what you would like to achieve rather than expecting us to try to reverse engineer everything from a general description.

Comment: Edited question to clarify I am asking about an Apex capability rather than a query

Answer (score 2):

Without an actual example illustrating what it is you're trying to achieve it's hard to give a complete answer but it sounds like this *can* be solved with a single query using scalar subquery

If I understand it correctly then this example illustrates what you need:
*"I have a (1) classic report on the emp table, but I need to show - for each employee - also (2) the employee in the department with the highest salary"* So (1) is the classic report and (2) is the additional query that needs to be run for each row in (1).

The base query would be

```
select e.empno,
       e.ename,
       e.job,
       e.mgr,
       e.hiredate,
       e.sal,
       e.comm,
       e.deptno
  from emp e;
```

and for each employee we'd have to run this query:

```
select ename
  from ( select ename,
                row_number()
                over(
                    order by sal desc
                ) as rn
  from emp
 where deptno = <the department of the employee>
       )
 where rn = 1
```

Now the 2 queries above can be merged into a single one. The 2nd query needs to return NULL or exactly 1 row and 1 column for this work and then it can be used as a **scalar subquery expression**. Within the inner query you can join to the outer query. (`deptno = e.deptno`)

```
select e.empno,
       e.ename,
       e.job,
       e.mgr,
       e.hiredate,
       e.sal,
       e.comm,
       e.deptno,
       ( select ename
         from ( select ename,
                       row_number()
                       over(
                           order by sal desc
                       ) as rn
         from emp
        where deptno = e.deptno
              )
        where rn = 1
       ) as big_earner
  from emp e;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I was hoping there may be a way around it in Apex without modifying the original query, sort of like a classic report cell capability to fire off it's own query like you can do with a normal Apex display text item for example. However if that's not the case and I have to change the query then your example is just what I needed!